# Erro no PHP 7: Call to undefined function sql_regcase

Tags: php

Alguém sabe como ficaria essa função no PHP 7?

```
function AntiSqlInjection($dados){       
     if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc){
       addslashes($dados);
     }       

     $dados= strip_tags($dados);          
       $dados= preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables)/"),'', $dados);  
       return $dados;      
}//end

$usuario= AntiSqlInjection($usuario);
$senha= AntiSqlInjection($senha);
```

Comment: Obsoleto: [sql_regcase](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sql-regcase.php)

Comment: Não há necessidade de criar um  antSqljection para versões mais novas do php você pode apenas utilizar uma conexão PDO que alem de tudo é muito  mais fácil de se configurar caso depois queira mudar o tipo de Banco de  dados

Comment: Procure sempre utilizar as extensões do **PDO** ou **MySQLi** que fazem o tratamento dos dados a serem processados pelas *queries* através dos *Prepared Statements*: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Em pleno php7 você usando essa função que nem funciona direito a melhor opção é utilizar prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

O [`sql_regcase`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sql-regcase.php) ficou obsoleto a bastante tempo, você pode tentar usar como alternativa os:

- [`preg_match()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
- [`preg_quote()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

Claro que vai ter que adaptar o código e ler a documentação de como usar, não basta *trocar*, no entanto se tratando de MySql e que você esta querendo fazer é um *anti-injection* eu realmente recomendo que ao invés de fazer tudo isso simplesmente use as funções prontas das APIs novas que já existem

Provavelmente você esta usando a API antiga ainda que as funções tem como prefixo isto `mysql_`, se estiver difícil de ajustar os códigos para as apis mais modernas como **PDO** ou **MYSQLi** então use simplesmenete:

- [`mysql_real_escape`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (que óbviamente esta obsoleta também pois faz parte da API antiga pois começa com `mysql_`)

Deve ficar assim:

```
$usuario= mysql_real_escape($usuario);
$senha= mysql_real_escape($senha);
```

No entanto é altamente recomendável que mude seus códigos o quanto antes possível para PDO ou para MYSQLI, pois as funções com prefixo `mysql_` já não funcionam nas versões mais recentes do PHP (*php 7+*) e por isto mais cedo ou mais tarde precisará migrar para um servidor com php7 (se por acaso seu servidor usa PHP5), recomendo que leia:

- [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635)

Se for usar a API mysqli um exemplo simples para evitar a injeção é usar [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), exemplo:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexão falhou: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['senha']);

if (mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login='$login' AND senha='$senha')")) {
    ... resto do código aqui
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Ou pode preferir ***[prepared statments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)*** do qual não precisará escapar as strings:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexão falhou: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

/* Prepara uma instrução */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login=? and senha=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $usuario);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $senha);

    /* executa a query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    ... resto do código aqui ...

    /* fecha o statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* fecha a conexão */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score 1):

está é uma função que foi  deprecated (ficou obsoleta) há muitos anos
mas você pode gerar algo generico

```
function my_Sql_regcase($str){

    $res = "";

    $chars = str_split($str);
    foreach($chars as $char){
        if(preg_match("/[A-Za-z]/", $char)){
             $res .= "[".mb_strtoupper($char, 'UTF-8').mb_strtolower($char, 'UTF-8')."]";
        }else{
            $res .= $char;
        }
     }

     return $res;
}
```

Pode utilizar a função da seguinte forma

```
$dados= preg_replace(my_Sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables)/"),'', $dados);
```

Comment: Oi, com essa consigo adicionar as palavras que quero restringir, como select|insert|where ? como ficaria?

Comment: Alterei a resposta

Comment: valeu, vou ver como fica

Comment: Coloquei mas não foi assim

Comment: quando adiciono no campo assim: $usuario= $dados($usuario); não pega no 7